# Why is my Native generation strategy not creating an id on SQLServer only?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a Java WebApplication which uses Spring and Hibernate to create and populate a table. The table has a unique id which is set by the following Hibernate configuration:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.myco.TransactionImpl" table="myco_transaction">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">id_column_sequence</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="user" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="tx_user" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </property>
   ...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This works fine for all of our MySQL users. However one users who is using SQLServer 2008 Developer Edition seems to find that whenever the application attempts to put a value into this table, the system throws an error of the type:

```
WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 339, SQLState: S0001
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
ERROR Exception - Error attempting to save instance:
```

This error seems quite clear. The id has not been generated. But why?

We have tried to resolve this issue in-house using SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server Express 2008 however when we use either of those systems, the insert into the table works and the ids are automatically generated.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. I believe that the problem is one of the following:

1. The user has somehow modified his database to not create sequences. If this is possible how do I go about reproducing this or asking the user how to check?
2. There is something fundamentally different about SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition.
3. The hibernate generation strategy is wrong for SQL Server 2008.

Any help or advice on how to proceed with this issue greatly appreciated.

**Update** :

Table Definition on the SQL Server 2008 machine:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myco_transaction](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[tx_user] [varchar](255) NULL,
[tx_date] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
[restored_tx] [int] NULL,
[restored_maint_urn] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ds_action] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Update:**

The user has stated this also fails on his version of SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition.

Comment: What is the table definition on the SQL Server 2008 box?  From the error, it sounds like they have a non-nullable identity column defined.

Comment: @TTeeple I've added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

Since the identity is already defined on the table and working, you don't need to insert it.  The table will automatically generate it upon insertion.  If you are wanting to insert your own identity, you will need to run an `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` command before doing the insert.  A word of warning, the insert will error if you are trying to insert an already generated identity.  This type of operation is usually done on a fresh and empty table.

Comment: The identity appears to be defined on the table but not actually working. The question is why does it not work? BTW I am assuming that the line: [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  shows the incrementor on the table.  Is there some way to say to a database, never generate a sequence even if the table states tone should be generated?  Also I don't want to manually put values in, my Java application should be doing that.

Comment: No, the identity is generated on every insert.  The only way to have it not be generated is if you do the `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` before inserting.  The application should NOT be the one determining identity values, that should fall to the database.  Take the id out of the insertion and it should run.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment and you are right. The database NOT the application SHOULD be inserting values into the column "id". However the database is not doing this for the user using SQL Server Developer Edition 2008. Why should it not be doing this only on his version? I cannot reproduce this locally. It works for me when I use SQL Server 2008 (Express Edition).

Comment: It sounds like his table definition is not what you are expecting. Developer edition has everything Express does and more.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The issue was something else entirely - it was due to the application crashing under certain conditions and NOTHING to do with the version of SQL Server. However since you helped and increased my knowledge of IDENTITY I'll upvote your answer. Thanks again for taking the time to help out.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you were able to figure it out!